# unable to push dynamic content using foreach in Angular 2, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, object

I am using reactive forms in Angular and I am getting data from the input fields. but before I push data to some variable, I have to do some processing.

```
//here data contains all the form data submitted using the form
let data = this.someForm.value;
```

one of the input field value contains comma separated values like this: `"45,756,879,345"`. I split it into an array of values using `','` and convert it to integer.

```
//Get all numbers in an array
let arr = data['c'].split(',').map(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item);
});
```

Now I loop through each of these arr values and push it to a variable called xyz. here, xyz is of some custom type I defined in the Model.

## what I get

```
[
{
  a: 'some data',
  b: 'some more data'
  c: 4
},
{
  a: 'some data',
  b: 'some more data'
  c: 4
},
{
  a: 'some data',
  b: 'some more data'
  c: 4

},... 10 more objects
]
```

## what I expect

```
[
{
  a: 'some data',
  b: 'some more data'
  c: 3
},
{
  a: 'some data',
  b: 'some more data'
  c: 46
},
{
  a: 'some data',
  b: 'some more data'
  c: 21

},... 10 more objects
]
```

## my approach for push dynamic data

```
//here I am trying to push same data for 'a' and 'b' but dynamic data for temp['c'].

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    temp['a'] = 'some data';
    temp['b'] = 'some more data';
    temp['c'] = arr[i];

    this.xyz.push(temp);
}
```

if I have 10 numbers in arr. then I get 10 array of objects in xyz 
when I print xyz. I see all xyz objects containing same temp['c'] value which is whatever arr contains as last value.

Comment: Please try to console.log your array and show us what you get

Answer (score 2):

You're likely using the same reference over and over again.

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var temp = {};
    temp['a'] = 'some data';
    temp['b'] = 'some more data';
    temp['c'] = arr[i];

    this.xyz.push(temp);
}
```

If you defined `temp` before that for loop you would just continuously edit the same `temp` over and over again pushing it into your `this.xyz` array.

If you don't even want a `temp` variable:

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    this.xyz.push({
        a: 'some data',
        b: 'some more data',
        c: arr[i]
    });
}
```

Comment: I get this: `Argument of type '{ a: any; b: boolean; c: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Xyz'.
  Property 'a' is private in type 'Xyz' but not in type '{ a: any; b: boolean; c: any; }'`.  I have defined `xyz : Xyz [] = [];`  when I push data as you mentioned I get error

Comment: I think it matters on the definition of temp you're using.

Comment: I tried to have it as any and same as of type Xyz Model

Comment: if I change `xyz: Xyz[] = []` to `xyz = []` it works.

Comment: Great, you didn't have that in the code above so I couldn't see it.

Comment: I am still not sure why cant I add my model type to the variable xyz? I do want to add it. but then it throws error as per previous comment.

Comment: if I change Access modifier in my model from private to public then it works but if I set it to Private does not work. how can I fix that?